# Problem when using `std::unordered_map` to map to a `std::list` object

Tags: c++

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::list<int>> sb;
sb[1].push_back(2);
```

I found that if I do this, then 1 element existed in the `unordered_map`, but element 2 was not pushed into the `std::list`. I am really confounded by this as it created a bug in one of my projects. May I ask why this wouldn't work? When I replaced `std::list` with `std::vector`, it worked.

Comment: Can you show a full reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue. The C Lion debugger showed the list as empty but in fact it was not. Likely because I set the breakpoint after the map initialization.